# Does compiler adjust int size?

Tags: c++, types, int

I wonder if in that case, compiller will adjust int variable size to its maximum possible value? Or will it use whole 32 bit int?

```
pseudocode:

int func()
{
    if (statement)
        return 10;
    else if (statement2)
        return 50;
    else
        return 100;
}

// how much memory will be alocated as it needs only 1 byte?
```

Comment: The memory required depends on where the result of the function is being used.

Comment: `int` uses an implementation defined fixed length of bytes (usually 4).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth
So if I assign it to short (short i = func()) it will alocate int size and then cast it on short? Or will it only alocate short size?

Comment: @user2843974, The former, but you have to realize what goes in the register is bigger than the `short` anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function returns `int`, the allocated memory will be `sizeof(int)`, regardless of the actual value stored in it.

Comment: First of all it's `sizeof`, not `sizof`; secondly, all you said was "the size of an int is the size of an int", which I hardly think is useful.

Answer (score 4):

I will use the full 32 bits (assuming that an int is 32 bits on this architecture).

It is defined at compile time

Answer (score 0):

Yes friend it will use whole 32 bit because the memory allocation to the primitive types is done at compile time.

Comment: @user2843974 you can crosscheck that by using sizeOf opertaor

Answer (score -1):

Int32 is value type. It is stored on stack on compile time. If it is inside any object then it will go to heap which is dynamic memory.

In your case, for any return value, compiler will allocate fixed bits on stack to store your return integer value, according to the size of int32  that is 32 bits, which can have range –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 if singed and 0 to 4,294,967,295 if unsigned.